# How to change the selected item's background color in android navigation drawer?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am using Navigation Drawer (using Navigation Drawer Activity) in android studio and its working fine.

But I want to change the Background Color of selected item in Drawer's item List. I want to change default Color to my custom Color.

Any idea ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create another xml layout under res ⇒ drawable named list_item_bg_pressed.xml with following content.**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"><gradient
  android:startColor="@color/list_background_pressed"
  android:endColor="@color/list_background_pressed"
  android:angle="90" />
```

**Create Selector**

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_normal" android:state_activated="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_activated="true"/>
```

**For more info see this link [Sliding drawer](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)**

Comment: @Vishal..i tried your answer but its not working for me.